# Why does the program stop functioninng unexpectedly?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have written a program that uses a while loop to run forever with a sleep interval provided by a .cfg file read by config parser.

It runs fine, for twenty-six or so days. Then it stops running, but of course stays running since it is launched as a service. Moreover, at the time I did not think for wrapping the main loop in a try exception block and log using import syslog.

The code sample below includes just the main block. I did not include the rest, as most of it is just a typical task queue and results queue form the multiprocessing module.

What could cause such behavior? Did my network device objects get garbage collected since they are not instantiated with each run through the while loop?   Is this just a bad way to code/design a long running Python program?

```
if __name__ == '__main__':

#
#Hold results in the multiprocessing queues
#
monitor_results = ''

#
#Our task is to monitor and this will hold our tasks
#
monitors = []

# 
# list of network devices represented as 
# objects that will be monitored
#
device_list = []

#
# The addresses of the devices are provided by the config parser's
# .cfg file
#
device_addresses = list(config['monitored']['devices'].split(','))

for address in device_addresses:
        password = get_password(address)
        device_list.append( Device(address, 'admin', password))

for d in device_list:
    path = ['sys', 'clock']
    request = Transport(headers, timeout=20)
    request.http.credentials.add(user, passwd)
    request.url = DeviceUri(d.mgmt_address, path ).uri
    monitors.append(request)


while True:

    tasks = multiprocessing.JoinableQueue(maxsize=len(monitors) + 1)
    results = multiprocessing.Queue()

    num_consumers = multiprocessing.cpu_count() * 2
    consumers = [Consumer(tasks, results) for i in range(num_consumers)]

    for w in consumers:
        w.start()

    for monitor in monitors:
        tasks.put(Monitor(monitor))

    for i in range(num_consumers):
        tasks.put(None)

    tasks.join()

    count = 0

    while not results.empty():
        result = results.get()
        if result is not None:
            monitor_results += result + '\n'
            count += 1

    if count > 0:
        mail_result = send_email( monitor_results )

    #
    #reset the monitor results or it will keep sending all previous results
    #
    monitor_results = ''

    time.sleep(poll_interval)
```

Comment: Have you checked the exit code, maybe exit not normally.

Comment: Nooobie question on my part...where would I find the exit code?

Comment: After your program exit. Use `echo $?` to check if you are using `*nix`

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to this.  Since I had my generated logs rotated via logrotate.d, they were removing the logs as opposed to truncating.  When the timer would re-start the loop, the program couldn't find the log file to write and exited.  Therefore, I reconfigured logrotate.d to 'copytruncate' instead of create.